# SQL Joins with Example Schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following schema:

```
*Project*
ID(PK)  NAME
1       Alpha
2       Bravo
3       Charlie
4       Delta

*Employee*
ID(PK)  NAME
1       Kevin
2       Mike
3       Eric
4       Ira
5       Peter

*Project Assignment*
ID(PK)  ProjectID(FK)   EmployeeID(FK)
1       1               1
2       1               2
3       2               2
4       2               3
5       3               3
6       3               4
7       1               3
```

And I would like to write queries which will:

1) Display all assigned projects and its team members.

Desired output:

```
Project TeamMembers
Alpha   Eric
Alpha   Kevin
Alpha   Mike
Bravo   Eric
Bravo   Mike
Charlie Eric
Charlie Ira
```

2) Display only the Alpha project and its team members, and which shows the names of the team members sorted in descending order.

Desired output:

```
ID      TeamMember
Alpha   Mike
Alpha   Kevin
Alpha   Eric
```

What would the simplest queries to do so look like?

ADDITIONAL QUESTION:

What would query be to sum the number of team members on each project?

Desired Result:

```
+-------------+-------------+
| ProjectName | NumMembers |
+-------------+-------------+
| Alpha       | 3           |
| Bravo       | 2           |
| Charlie     | 2           |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: You need to understand table relationships. Your question is so obscure. 
From what I see, it hard to achieve your query simply your table relationship mapping is poor. Kindly redesign you table in a much effective way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table Project (ID int,  NAME varchar(50));

insert into Project values
(1, 'Alpha'),
(2, 'Bravo'),
(3, 'Charlie'),
(4, 'Delta');

create table Employee (ID int,  NAME varchar(50));

insert into Employee values
(1, 'Kevin'), 
(2, 'Mike'),
(3, 'Eric'),
(4, 'Ira'),
(5, 'Peter');

create table Project_Assignment (ID int,  ProjectID int,  EmployeeID int);

insert into Project_Assignment values
(1, 1,  1),
(2, 1,  2),
(3, 2,  2),
(4, 2,  3),
(5, 3,  3),
(6, 3,  4),
(7, 1,  3);
```

**Solution# 1:**

You will need to join your `Project_Assignment` table to both `Project` and `Employee` tables to get your two columns respectively:

```
select p.name as projectname,
       e.name as TeamMembers   
from project_assignment pa
join project p on pa.projectid = p.id
join employee e on pa.employeeid = e.id
order by projectname, TeamMembers desc;
```

**Result:**

```
+-------------+-------------+
| projectname | TeamMembers |
+-------------+-------------+
| Alpha       | Mike        |
| Alpha       | Kevin       |
| Alpha       | Eric        |
| Bravo       | Mike        |
| Bravo       | Eric        |
| Charlie     | Ira         |
| Charlie     | Eric        |
+-------------+-------------+
```

[<kbd>**SQL Fiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3d0d/3/0)

**Solution# 2:**

Add a `where` clause in above query to filter `Alpha` project only:

```
select p.name as projectname,
       e.name as TeamMembers   
from project_assignment pa
join project p on pa.projectid = p.id
join employee e on pa.employeeid = e.id
where p.name = 'Alpha'
order by projectname, TeamMembers desc;
```

**Result:**

```
+-------------+-------------+
| projectname | TeamMembers |
+-------------+-------------+
| Alpha       | Mike        |
| Alpha       | Kevin       |
| Alpha       | Eric        |
+-------------+-------------+
```

[<kbd>**SQL Fiddle Demo 2**</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3d0d/6/0)

Comment: Actually, I have another followup question: What would the query look like which would show the total number of team members for each project: